# Uneven distribution of data to reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, reduce

I have a harmless looking Hive query which takes some data from one table to overwrite into another. Both source and destination tables are partitioned. The destination table is also clustered.

This query spawns 4 MR jobs, with the last one always taking unusually large amounts of time in the reduce phase. I tried increasing the number of reducers, but that didn't help. On looking deeper, I noticed that 1 out of the specified 130 reducers (initially 1 out of the default 26 reducers) always seemed to be receiving much more data than the rest. I further tried using the distribute clause on a column with good distribution, but that didn't help either.

Is there a way I can figure out what's the reason most data seems to go to one reducer? Alternatively, any suggestions on how to control this data volume would be immensely helpful.

My code (table and column names changed). 
Destination is partitioned on columns l and m
Destination is clustered by user_id

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
set mapred.reduce.tasks=130;

insert overwrite table dest_table
select
  coalesce(event_guid, "<UNKNOWN>") event_guid,
  coalesce(a, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(b, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(user_id, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(c, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(d, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(e, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(f, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(g, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(h, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(i, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(j, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(k, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(l, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(m, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(n, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(o, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(p, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(q, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(r, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(to_date(from_utc_timestamp(s, "PST")), "0000-00-00"),
  coalesce(cast(from_utc_timestamp(s, "PST") as string), '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
  coalesce(s, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
  coalesce(t, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
  coalesce(u, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
  coalesce(cast(from_utc_timestamp(t, "PST") as string), '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
  coalesce(cast(from_utc_timestamp(u, "PST") as string), '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
  coalesce(to_date(from_utc_timestamp(u, "PST")), "0000-00-00"),
  coalesce(v, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(w, "<UNKNOWN>"),
  coalesce(x, "<UNKNOWN>")
from
  source raw
where v is not null and w is not null and x is not null
distribute by event_guid
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion but can you try your own mapper and reducer scripts using TRANSFORM or MAP/REDUCE keyword in hive to control the data. For e.g. choose the key to be a column that gives even distribution (which is what you are trying to achieve using distribute by)
Do might need to so some HQL analysis. Run a group by, count(*) on event_guid. Are the counts evenly distributed ?